# Eclipse presentation mode

Tags: eclipse

Is there a plugin which supports for presentations in Eclipse ?
That means, assume the code is required to present for a couple of people and if the code is showed as it is, all tools, menu bars and all other icons are shown. Instead, I want to show only the tab which code is open (it can be a class,html or css file) in a full screen so that the PC can be connected to a projector and whole audience sees the opened tab only.

I have seen this in IntelijIdea, but not in eclipse. Any Suggestion please? I use Luna.

Comment: What I do in presentations:
1. Double-click tab, so it's maximized.
2. Increase font size (there was a plugin providing buttons, but I can't find it anymore - instead, you could define custom keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 10):

Maximize the tab and **Ctrl+** (on Eclipse Neon)

Comment: Man, that is so simple! Now I know why Eclipse doesn't have "Presentation mode" like IntelliJ. It works on my Eclipse `Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800`

Comment: Well, it's not really the same thing. With large monitors and high-res laptop displays, most folks these days use a font size that's much much smaller than anything that would be suitable for presentation. For example, I have to press `Ctrl`-`+` four or five times to arrive at a font that's readable on a projector, and then, after the presentation, I have to press `Ctrl`-`-` the same number of times again, except sometimes I overshoot and have to press `Ctrl`-`+` again to compensate. The proposed solution is a work-around at best.

Answer (score 5):

The most recent version of the [saneclipse](http://saneclipse.vogella.com/documentation.html) plugin has a [full screen mode](http://blog.vogella.com/2015/10/09/eclipse-neon-and-saneclipse-adding-full-screen-mode-for-eclipse/).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks.. It brings me somewhat I expected..  If it hides the title bar or the top frame bar, it would be awesome .. !!

Comment: The most recent version of Eclipse IDE (Neon, released June 2016) directly supports fullscreen: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/#full-screen-feature

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ctrl+M which will maximize an active view or editor.

Also, use Alt+F11 for toggle full screen.